# javascript - How to assign json data to an HTML element and send to API onclick?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a javascript framework wherein I can enable users to store Items, Description, Price etc. in ecommerce sites in their account for future reference. The way I'm trying to do this is to create a button next to every item that says 'Save Item', get the item details in the form of a JSON and send it to an API where the user can access it later.

So far I'm stuck with some fundamental design questions:

Assuming the JSON has only four fields - 1)ItemName 2) Item Price 3) Item Description 4) Retailer Item URL

1) How do I store the four fields and assign them to a HTML button - The approach I've taken is to create a class to detect the type of button, but I'm storing the details of all items of the page in an array and getting the clicked button item details, putting it in a json and making a post request using jQuery

2) Some research shows that KnockoutJS can help. Apparently I can store the json as an attribute of the HTML button of the item. Is that safe?

3) How do you pass an API key(unique for every ecommerce retailer) along with the JSON to the API?

I'm new to JavaScript and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can pass the JSON (and all the extra stuff) to your server using an [`AJAX call`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) (real easy with jQuery), then have your server send it to the external server. You can build the JSON using data from fields in your HTML markup, sure. Mock up some HTML and JSON, and try out the `$.ajax` call, and then post your code here if you have difficulty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this **http://tinker.io/37211**

**Items HTML**

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
 <tr>
    <td> Product 1 </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="SaveItemButton"
        data-item-name="Product 1" data-item-price="1" data-item-description="Description 1" data-retailer-item-url="URL 1">
            Save Item
        </button>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td> Product 2 </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="SaveItemButton"
        data-item-name="Product 2" data-item-price="2" data-item-description="Description 2" data-retailer-item-url="URL 2" />
            Save Item
        </button>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**And JavaScript included**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script>
    (function($){ 
        window.SomeApiKey = '';

        // This is the JS file contents which will be saved as file somewhere and included like the jQuery library above
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.SaveItemButton').click(function(){

                var btn = $(this);

                // colect data
                var data = {'item-name': btn.data('item-name'),  
                            'item-price': btn.data('item-price'), 
                            'item-description': btn.data('item-description'), 
                            'retailer-item-url': btn.data('retailer-item-url'), 
                            'api-key': window.SomeApiKey};

                // this line just for testing
                alert(' will send :' + $.param( data ) );   

                // do JSONP request
                $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "http://www.site.com",
                   dataType: "jsonp",
                   data: data
                }).done(function( msg ) {
                   alert( msg );
                });

                return false;
            });
        });

     })(jQuery);  
 </script>

  <script>
    // here the client will set APIkey to use
    window.SomeApiKey = 'APIKEY';
 </script>
```

Comment: Michael - Thanks for the response. I don't want the retailer to be responsible for the transmission of data after the click. It would simply be better if I can tell the retailer to populate the HTML element with the data, and handle all the onClick routines in a background javascript that would be universal and won't depend on the serverside scripting language used by the retailer. Does that sound right?

Comment: that is just sample javascript code to submit the json data, "some.php" just represents your API public URL

Comment: I think I might have put my point in a different way. The way I'm looking at is this - Let the retailer populate the element. All the buttons will have the same class. jQuery can detect the class when it is clicked. Now, it should gather all the data pertaining to the element, make a JSON out of it and make a POST request. So essentially the retailer needs to populate the data of the element(how?). The background javascript file will do the rest, including detecting the onClick. I don't want the retailer to make the ajax call. The background .js file will do that after detecting a click

Answer (score 1):

If you want to attach data use the data attribute of HTML5 and get the data from JQUery like this:

```
<button id="myButtonId" data-ItemName="your value" data-ItemPrice="10.00" data-ItemDescription="Your description" >Your button</button>
```

Then with JQuery you can retrieve the data or set the data, see the JQuery manual for the topic:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/